# What is the highest number of up-votes and down-votes that a question can earn?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, upvotes

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) is by far the highest up-voted question and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly) is the most down-voted question based on this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites/11022#11022) in SO.

What is the highest number of up-votes and down-votes that a question can earn?

Comment: 2147483647​​​​​

Comment: More like `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. We have to account for Jon.

Comment: "Is there any maximum limit to up-vote a question ?" - Yes. One per account.

Comment: @Gimby :D :D :D OP asking another thing. And question meaning is another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Overflow is using SqlServer as its underlying database. We don't know the exact [database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) but it is believed that what we find in [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is close to the real thing.

The `score` is stored in the `posts` tables and from the [information_schema](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/438556/score-in-posts-information-schema) we learn that the datatype is `int`. Looking up the actual maximum values for that type in the [online documentation for Sql Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187745.aspx) gives us:

> 2,147,483,647

that is the number [Rizier123](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) mentioned as well.

Now that we know the technical maximum limit we have to figure out how that score field get its value.

The score goes up by one if a user with at least [15 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) up votes the post. Every user can only vote once on a post. If you would start today and every single user with [at least 15 rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/438545) would all up-vote the same post the maximum score a post could get would be:

> 1,175,540

This number could in theory be a bit higher if you would take into account all users that ever existed on the site, had more than 15 rep and all decided before they left/the account was abandoned to up-vote that single post. But for that we would have to rewrite history which I leave to others.

It is too bad you didn't ask for the lowest score a post can get because that is more interesting.

Users can still put a negative score of around that 1,172,540 on a post. But after that the community can add an extra negative bonus of -6 if they raise 6 [spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035) because a spam flags carry an extra down vote which is given by the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user. Now I assume that if moderators reverse a spam flag on a post, also the score gets adjusted. If not we've found a way to let a post go even further down.

Comment: I only believe this when I see 1,175,540 upvotes on this answer :)

Comment: I'm more interested in the down vote scenario, so let's organize that @Rizier123

Comment: I wanted to ask about down-votes too, but I thought that would be too broad to ask. Now, I would like to edit my question just for your very useful answer @rene

Comment: Do spam and abusive auto-downvotes stack? If so, 11 users could flag with a 5/6 split to get 11 lower than the number of downvoters, of which there are 398682 in SEDE.

Comment: I don't believe they stack @NathanTuggy, internally it is one flag IIRC, the spam flag is only used to indicate that the post should feed the spam detection/raise the spam alarm. Might be worth an experiment ...